# clickListener is not working in GridView in android app

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I am implementing an android application that has a `GridView` where every item is an `ImageView` with `TextView` below, I implemented the adapter and the `GridView` displays correctly, but it is supposed that when I click an image an other screen (Activity is launched) but unfortunately it is not the case here is my code:

the gridView_layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videosGrid"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:background="#000"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"></GridView>


</GridLayout>
```

the grid_item_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:minWidth="170dp"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/alternative_rock_music" -->

    <TextView android:id="@+id/video_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

the adapter:

```
package com.app.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.R;
import com.app.entities.VideoEntity;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private static final String TAG =  MyGridViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private List<VideoEntity> videosList;


    public MyGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videosList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return videosList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public List<VideoEntity> getVideosList() {
        return videosList;
    }

    public void setVideosList(List<VideoEntity> videosList) {
        this.videosList = videosList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Log.d(TAG," getView(int, View, viewGroup - Ini ");

        View row  =  convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_item ,parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        VideoEntity tmp = videosList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(tmp.getThumbnailURL()).into(holder.myVideo);
        holder.title.setText(tmp.getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, " getView(int, View, viewGroup - Fi ");
        return row;

    }

    class ViewHolder {

        ImageView myVideo;
        TextView  title;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG," ViewHolder(View) - Ini ");
                myVideo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
                title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            Log.d(TAG," ViewHolder(View) - Fi ");
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the activity where i am supposed to catch the click event on every item of the gridView:

```
package com.app.activities

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.app.entities.VideoEntity;
import com.app.utils.MyGridViewAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.widget.AdapterView.*;




public class VideosCatalogActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener{


    private static final String TAG =  VideosCatalogActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GridView videosGrid;

    private ArrayList<VideoEntity> videosList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        Log.d(TAG, " onCreate(Bundle) - Ini ");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.videos_catalog_layout);
        Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
        videosList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("com.app.entities.VideoEntity" );

        videosGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videosGrid);
        MyGridViewAdapter adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this);
        adapter.setVideosList(videosList);
        videosGrid.setAdapter(adapter);



        videosGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        Log.d(TAG, " onCreate(Bundle) - Fi ");
    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.d(TAG, " onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) - Ini ");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID",videosList.get(position).getId());
        startActivity(intent);

        Log.d(TAG, " onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) - Fi ");


    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.d(TAG, " onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) - Ini ");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID",videosList.get(position).getId());
        startActivity(intent);

        Log.d(TAG, " onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) - Fi ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    } */
}
```

I tried to implement two different onClickListeners methods but none is working.
I don't know what i did wrong ???

Any help will be very appreciated.

**Note:** i can confirm that it is not a manifest problem, because i debugged and nothing happens when i click an image.

Comment: i guess you need to setOnItemClickListener on the adapter

Comment: @dadan inside the adapter class ??

Comment: Please note that your, VideosCatalogActivity, is implemented with onClickListener, not onItemClickListener. You have nothing inside onClick(View v). Hope that help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
`implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener`
```

to

```
`implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`
```

Change

```
`videosGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`
```

to

```
`videosGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this)`
```

Remove `android:clickable="true"` in ImageView

Comment: @rainman I tried your code, `implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener` change to `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. `videosGrid.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` change to `videosGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);`, ClickListener worked.

Comment: In your item layout, you set ImageView `android:clickable="true"`. if you use OnItemClickListener and not use OnClickListener for ImageView. once you click on the imageView, OnItemClickListner will not work. I suggest to remove `android:clickable="true"` in ImageView

Comment: Thanks it worked, i suggest you modify you answer with what you put in the commentaries so i accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both interfaces 
`AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
 AdapterView.OnClickListener` and respective methods.

and implement the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify that **`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`** is different to **`AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`** and **`AdapterView.OnClickListener`** also.

Your activity should implement **`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`**, override it and you will get item click event. Remember to add this line: **`videosGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this)`**.